# Using XHR to precache resources not behaving as expected

Tags: javascript, ajax, caching

I'm simply trying to use XHR to precache some resources, but the cache is not behaving as expected.

Here are the bounds of the problem:

- I know the resource URLs in advance (of course).
- I don't know their content-types (mix of CSS, images, and other).
- They will always be same-origin.
- I control the cache headers.
- They can be cached forever for all I care.

I've always been under the impression that XHR used the browser cache more or less like any other resource, but never rigorously tested that. Here's what I'm doing:

- Request all resources up-front with XHR.
- Explicitly set request header `Cache-Control: max-age=3600` (Chrome was setting `max-age=0` for some reason).
- Set the following response headers on the server:

  - `Cache-control: public; max-age=3600`
  - `Date: now`
  - `Expires: now + 1 hour`
  - `[Content-Type, Content-Length]`

Here's what I'm seeing:

- XHR **always** fetches the resource (confirmed on server and with dev tools).
- Subsequent requests (via image/css/etc elements) always fetch (even after the XHRs have completed) on a cold cache.
- But they always use the cache when it's warm.

I've poked at it in various ways, but this behavior never seems to change.

Comment: What do you mean by "Subsequent requests (via image/css/etc elements) always fetch (even after the XHRs have completed) on a cold cache." Are you creating the `<script>`/`<img>` elements dynamically at some later point?

Comment: That's correct. The idea was to use XHR requests to warm the cache, then hope that later dynamically-created script/img elements would fetch from the warm cache.

Answer (score 0):

After much wailing and gnashing of teeth, I believe I've proven that this approach simply won't work on all browsers. Here's my experience thus far:

- **Firefox**: Works a charm.
- **Chrome**: Seldom works -- it's as though XHR uses a different cache than the elements (even though I'm pretty sure that's not the case; I haven't had time to delve into Chrome code to figure out exactly what's going on.
- **Safari**: Apparently random. Sometimes resource requests kicked off from elements retrieve from the cache, sometimes not. I'm sure there's a method, but it appears to be madness from the outside.

In the end, I had to switch to the somewhat more craptastic-but-reliable approach of creating a hidden iframe, injecting script/img elements into it, then waiting on the iframe window's onload event. This works, but gives no fine-grained feedback in terms of which elements are loaded (getting reliable onload events from the individual elements is more "cross-browser tricky" than just waiting on the whole frame.

I'd love to understand more precisely what's going on in Chrome/Safari, but sadly don't have the time to dig in further.